# When testing an open source program using AFL, how would you analyze whether crashes you get are a vulnerability, and what kind of vulnerability?

Tags: security, crash, fuzzing

When testing a program using AFL(American fuzzy lop), I get a lot of unique crashes. Is there any way to help me analyze the crashes I test, determine what kind of crashes they are and where in the source code it's happening?

Can this be done with gdb or ASAN?

Comment: A crash is a DoS vulnerability. If you want to know if the bug that led to the crash is exploitable in another way (RCE and other), the only way is to write a working exploit.